# jQuery: Selecting elements and using the attr() function on 'live' bindings

Tags: css, dom, jquery-selectors, jquery

I want to select an Input checkbox element via jQuery and dynamically tick or untick it.

I am using code like this:

```
$('input#my_input').attr('checked', true);
```

Perfectly valid - and that works just fine. However, these Input elements are being dynamically styled by jQuery Uniform CSS - http://uniformjs.com/ - a very nice jQuery library to custom-style elements.

The problem is that Uniform changes the DOM structure slightly by wrapping these elements in custom wrappers (although the input still has the ID I assigned it, etc). I want to use `$(...).live` with `attr` but I can't work out how to pass the `attr` parameters when using Live.

Can anybody help? Thanks!

**EDIT:** To make things a bit clearer, I've posted some more code below.

My PHP script is outputting a table of users. For each user is five areas of the site they either can or can't access, in each area they can perform a different task. These are just tickboxes. But I want to have a 'Preset' dropdown list that will automatically tick specific task/area access combinations.

Here's my Preset Switch event:

```
$('select.preset_switch').change(function() {

    var user_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var preset  = $(this).val();

    switch(preset)
    {
        case 'Area 1':
            setPermissions(user_id, true, true, true, true, true);
            break;

        case 'Area 2':
            setPermissions(user_id, true, true, true, true, true);
            break;

        case 'Area 3':
            setPermissions(user_id, true, true, true, true, true);
            break;

        case 'Area 4':
            setPermissions(user_id, true, true, true, true, true);
            break;

        case 'Area 5':
            setPermissions(user_id, true, true, true, true, true);
            break;

        case 'Area 6':
            setPermissions(user_id, true, true, true, true, true);
            break;

        case 'Inactive User':
            setPermissions(user_id, false, false, false, false, false);
            break;
    }
});
```

The `setPermissions()` function:

```
// Sets the Input tickboxes for permissions editor
function setPermissions(user_id, task1, task2, task3, task4, task5)
{
    $('input#permission_task1_'+user_id ).live(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', task1);
    });
    $('input#permission_task2_'+user_id ).live(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', task2);
    });
    $('input#permission_task3_'+user_id ).live(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', task3);
    });
    $('input#permission_task4_'+user_id     ).live(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', task4);
    });
    $('input#permission_task5_'+user_id ).live(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', task5);
    });
}
```

I know for now, everything is set to 'true' - this is just to make testing clearer. I will set up proper access configurations later on.

Finally, my HTML looks like this (one row of many dynamic ones):

```
<tr>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="area1[]" id="permission_task1_1044" class="permission_checkbox" value="1044"  />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="area2[]" id="permission_task2_1044" class="permission_checkbox" value="1044"  />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="area3[]" id="permission_task3_1044" class="permission_checkbox" value="1044"  />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="area4[]" id="permission_task4_1044" class="permission_checkbox" value="1044"  />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="area5[]" id="permission_task5_1044" class="permission_checkbox" value="1044"  />
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="preset_switch" id="1044">
            <option>Select a preset</option>
            <option>Area 1</option>
            <option>Area 2</option>
            <option>Area 3</option>
            <option>Area 4</option>
            <option>Area 5</option>
            <option>Area 6</option>
            <option>Inactive User</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT 2:** Problem solved. Had to use `$.uniform.update()` on my element so that uniform would visually update it - it was working correctly the first way I did it, just not refreshing the display. Still doesn't explain the error on `live()` but hey, it works!

Comment: did you try to use the proper `.prop()` jquery function, instead of `.attr()` ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - updated it to `prop()`, but things are still broken. :(

Comment: could you post the .live() code? I feel that the assignation is never made... (and not that attr/prop doesn't work)

Comment: Problem solved - fixed it. See Edit 2 :)

Comment: as I said in my answer, the problem lies within the live in the setPermissions function. You use no event in it, and jquery interprets it as an events map (object), expecting somthing like `{click: function() {...}}`. You send an jquery object ($('stuff') is an object), but not what the live function expects (an event map object).

Comment: correction `function() { $(this).prop('checked', task1); }` returns null, triggering a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'live' of null" error, but the base logic (misuse of .live() funtion) stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#the_trigger').live('the_event_you_are_binding_to', function(){
    $('#my_input').attr('checked', true);
    // return false; // depending on your needs
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit of a beginner at jQuery so forgive me if this is a silly question - but I'm not binding to any events. The event has already happened (the original event was a change of a `<select>` menu. I now just want to perform the action (changing `attr`) on a specific element - it's like there are no events occurring.

Comment: If you want to use `live` you need to bind to an event.  http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
$('input#my_input').live(function(){
   $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Chrome reports this in the error console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
     $(this).attr('checked', false);
    } has no method 'split'`

Comment: just a silly question, are you using jquery with another javascript library like prototype/mootools? it may be due to a conflict because the above code should work.

Comment: Nope - just jQuery, and the latest version too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need an Other event handler, you can check/uncheck checkboxes directly:

```
function setPermissions(user_id, task1, task2, task3, task4, task5)
{
    $('input#permission_task1_'+user_id ).prop('checked', task1);
    $('input#permission_task2_'+user_id ).prop('checked', task2);
    $('input#permission_task3_'+user_id ).prop('checked', task3);
    $('input#permission_task4_'+user_id ).prop('checked', task4);
    $('input#permission_task5_'+user_id ).prop('checked', task5);   
}
```

point is, you change the select, which triggers the setPermissions function. Do you want some special action when you click on the checkboxes??

[check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYEX4/)